# Removing the default DE

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, cinnamon

Recently, I installed Ubuntu MATE. Then, because I want Cinnamon and *only* Cinnamon and Cinnamon is basically all I care about, I did `apt remove mate-desktop` or something to that effect, rebooted, and `lightdm` refused to work and the only solution was reinstall.

So, I reinstalled, this time Lubuntu. I'd like to make the `L` in Lubuntu go away*, so its apps stop infringing upon my desktop, and so I don't have to deal with its ugliness.

I'm fearful, however, that doing `apt remove lubuntu-desktop` will remove *everything* that Core Ubuntu knows about, which is an issue.

How can I make `LXDE` (and openbox, if possible) go away without harming the integrity of my system?

As I understand Ubuntu, there's Official Ubuntu, running Unity, and then the Official Flavours are just different DEs and default packages, so in my understanding I can just purge what I don't want and end up with a functioning system. That doesn't seem to be the case, though.

---

*Why, then, did I install Lubuntu? Because I wanted a lightweight version of Ubuntu to build on, and UbuntuMinimalCD was being buggy.

Comment: What do you want to do after removing LXDE?

Comment: @Raphael I want to run just Awesome and Cinnamon, which seems to be going okay.

Comment: Will edit my answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WIP**

Regarding `lubuntu-desktop`, from `Synaptic:

> This metapackage package depends on all components of Lubuntu Desktop
>   system.
>
> It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, but it can be safely
>   removed if you want to remove some applications installed by default.

As it is just a meta package, so, removing it will not harm your environment at all. If you are still worried about the meta packages, then goto [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages):

> One of the handy features of apt (the packaging system used by Ubuntu)
>   is the use of metapackages. These packages do not contain actual
>   software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. This
>   setup allows entire sets of software to be installed by selecting only
>   the appropriate metapackage. For example, an Ubuntu user can install
>   the Kubuntu environment (KDE and all its associated programs) by
>   selecting "kubuntu-desktop."

In there, it says that meta packages do not contain actual software. And in this list it says lubuntu-desktop is a meta package. So, do not worry, go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Okay, that works, I think. But, all of LXDE's apps (`lxterminal`, etc) are installed. How can I remove all those packages? `lx*` doesn't work because the shell glob will evaluate to every package.

Comment: Never mind, there were fewer than I thought, I did it by hand.